# Can New Relic be used for Load testing?

Tags: web-applications, browser, response, newrelic

I have been trying to understand the features that New Relic offers. I want to be able to test the application server response time and the browser response time of my Ruby application deployed to JBOSS by load testing the application. Is this possible with new Relic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use New Relic to perform an actual load test, but it would make a lot of sense to have New Relic in place to monitor your application during your load test.

For doing the load test I would suggest a tool like Siege: http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/3936526/Load-Testing-and-Benchmarking-With-Siege.htm?mchk=1

Or a service like http://blazemeter.com/

Comment: Thanks Emil! Just started using blazemeter. Very simple to transfer data from new relic to blazemeter

Comment: Is there a good tutorial for integrating blazemeter into new relic dashboard?

Comment: I work at New Relic. There's an easy way to integrate blazemeter into the NR dashboard though there's no tutorial. Click on "plugins" in your NR account navigation sidebar, which will take you to a directory. Search for "blaze" and you'll find the plugin along with instructions for integration. Once you have it setup, you'll automatically get a "blazemeter" entry in that same nav sidebar, and therein should be metrics. Blaze supports their plugin here: http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/214577-blazemeter-plugin-for-new-relic . You'll have to ask them for further help.